# Insert selected columns from one table to selected columns of another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I am new to SQL Server thing and want to find a solution.

I have two tables `employees` and `new_employees`.

Table `employees` has columns:

```
id(pk) | username | phonenumber | createdby | deptid |date
```

Table `new_employees` has columns:

```
id(pk) | name, p_number | dept_id | ext_no | salary
```

I want to insert all the records from table `new_employees` with selected columns `name`, `p_number`, `dept_id'` to columns `username`, `phonenumber`, `deptid` of table `employees`.

But in `createdby` and `date` columns of table `employees`, I want to put two values 'John' and `getDate();`

Please help me to write query for this scenario.

Comment: The statement you are looking for is `INSERT` and it allows you to specify which columns to insert into and you can (among other things) insert the results of a `SELECT` statement. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: @mendosi yes through insert and select statement i can deal with common columns of both table but how to put values for columns **createdby** and **date** in table employees

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If he confusion is about mixing values from a table and literal values then you can use syntax of this form:

```
INSERT INTO Table (...)
SELECT col1, ... 'John', GetDate()
  FROM AnotherTable;
```